# Why if I import a library.jar, it is necessary to say the native library location?

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

I am working with java in eclipse, and to use opencv I need to import the library .jar (for me opencv-2.4.8.jar) and I need to specify the native library location (i.e. for libopencv_java248.so). If not, I get an error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java248 in java.library.path.

> So, why I need to do this reference? 
>   
>   why isn't it enough with import the opencv.jar library?

Comment: The native libraries are used to talk to the operating system. Sometimes, java doesn't provide the functions you need, so you have to write windows, mac, or linux code to get your library working. The native libraries are the machine specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a jar file only has Java code in it. OpenCV has more than just Java code, it also has some C/C++ code that is in the native library. That code can't be put in the jar, so it has to be put somewhere else, and you have to say where it is.

Comment: Ok, i get it. For my case, opencv.jar just make the connection from java to the native libraries of opencv.so / opencv.dll

Comment: If you see an answer that you think is satisfactory, you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark. (hint hint) See the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).